# How to optimize updating a record when using SQLAlchemy and Flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy with Flask and the Flask-SQLAlchemy extension. What I'm confused about is how to optimize the updating of a record. As a proof of concept I wrote the following endpoints:

```
@bp.route('/books', methods=['GET', 'PUT'], endpoint="books_index")
@bp.route('/books/<book_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'], endpoint="books_show")
def books_index(book_id=None):
    book = Book.query.get_or_404(book_id) if book_id else Book()
    form = Book.model_form(request.form, book if book_id else None)
    verb = "updated" if book_id else "created"

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.populate_obj(book)
        db.session.add(book)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Book %s successfully' % verb, 'info')

    return dict(
        books=[] if book_id else Book.query.all(), 
        book=book, 
        form=form
    )
```

Everything works as I want it to, but when updating an existing book record, SQLAlchemy runs three queries, they are:

1. SELECT book.id AS book_id, book.title AS book_title FROM book WHERE book.id = ?
2. UPDATE book SET title=? WHERE book.id = ?
3. SELECT book.id AS book_id, book.title AS book_title FROM book WHERE book.id = ?

I understand why SQLAlchemy makes all three queries, but it seems a bit excessive for simply updating one record. Is there a way to optimize the amount of queries happening here?

(as a note, I've got some wrapping on the endpoints to render templates based on a convention which is why you don't see `render_template`)